# Can an offset be added to i in for(var in range) to post consecutive e.parameters to unique spreadsheet cells?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a URL with parameters being POSTed to my Google App script that contains names of people, their age, address, phone number, etc.

On a spreadsheet I want to set each person's name on a unique row and cell with each of their details on the same row in their own unique columns and cells.

I have tried setting the value of each cell by adding an offset to the index of e.parameters. i.e. var val = e.parameters(i+1) but the value is then undefined as I'm not sure if that is the correct syntax to find an offset index.

So two problems:
How can I find the adjacent value(s) of i and set it to a unique cell?
How do I increment i to the next name?

Should I use a for loop instead of for/in?

```
https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwFxca76urW8A4TnRpU7y7DnDT7A_rO_rx1NNDAz9D70Y8b1u4/exec?name1=Johnny&age1=21&address1=21+Jump+Street&phonnenumber1=555-5555&name2=Nick&age2=180&address2=North+Pole&phonenumber2=555-55554&
name2=Charlie&age3=180&address3=WillyW+Wonkas&phonenumber1=555-55553
```

Script:

```
function doPost(e)
{
var sl = e.parameter;



 var props = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
 var ssNew, ssId = props.getProperty('ssId');    

 if (ssId) 

 {
    ssNew = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId);
    var sheet = ssNew.getSheets()[0];
   var range = sheet.getRange("A2:D100");
   range.clearContent();
   var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues(); 

   for (var row in headers) {
   for (var col in headers[row]) {

  var cell = sheet.getRange('a1');
  var col = 0;

      for (var i in e.parameters) {
      var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow();  
      val = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-7", "yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss");
        cell.offset(nextRow, col).setValue(val);
      col++;
       val = e.parameters[i];
        // get next row

       cell.offset(nextRow, col).setValue(val);
       col++; 
       val = e.parameters[i+1];
        // get next row

       cell.offset(nextRow, col).setValue(val); 
        col++; 
       val = e.parameters[i+2];
        // get next row

       cell.offset(nextRow, col).setValue(val);
       col = 0; 

    }    
    }
   }
   }


  else 
  {  
    ssNew = SpreadsheetApp.create("Contact List");
    props.setProperty('ssId', ssNew.getId());
  }  

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear why you put parameters in query string when making a POST request, but this is besides the point. The event object your doPost function receives is given below; I obtained this just by logging `JSON.stringify(e)`.

As you can see, neither e.parameter nor e.parameters are arrays, so `e.parameters[i+1]` makes no sense. They are objects, with the keys being parameter names. You could also learn this by [reading documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#url_parameters). So your web app must be aware of the key names, and use them appropriately.

One option is to consistently use "age", "name", "address", "phonenumber", without appending 1,2,3. Then `e.parameters.age` will be an array of all  ages, `e.parameters.name` an array of all names, etc.

The logic of rows/columns in your script seems okay, although I'd use the simpler `sheet.getRange(row, column)` instead of offset.

Event object:

```
{
    "parameter": {
        "phonenumber2": "555-55554",
        "phonenumber1": "555-55553",
        "address3": "WillyW Wonkas",
        "address2": "North Pole",
        "address1": "21 Jump Street",
        "age3": "180",
        "name2": "Nick",
        "name1": "Johnny",
        "phonnenumber1": "555-5555",
        "age2": "180",
        "age1": "21"
    },
    "contextPath": "",
    "contentLength": -1,
    "queryString": "name1=Johnny&age1=21&address1=21+Jump+Street&phonnenumber1=555-5555&name2=Nick&age2=180&address2=North+Pole&phonenumber2=555-55554&name2=Charlie&age3=180&address3=WillyW+Wonkas&phonenumber1=555-55553",
    "parameters": {
        "phonenumber2": ["555-55554"],
        "phonenumber1": ["555-55553"],
        "address3": ["WillyW Wonkas"],
        "address2": ["North Pole"],
        "address1": ["21 Jump Street"],
        "age3": ["180"],
        "name2": ["Nick", "Charlie"],
        "name1": ["Johnny"],
        "phonnenumber1": ["555-5555"],
        "age2": ["180"],
        "age1": ["21"]
    }
}
```

Comment: I managed to make it work with your suggestion. Thanks very much.